# Store list of tuples django model in easy to access way

Tags: python, django, list, tuples

I'm creating django application for online Barber Shop booking. I came out with an algorithm that store avaliable hours. Here is exaple how it works. Let's say that barber_1 works form 8am to 4pm. We store this date in list with tuple [(8, 16)] if someone book an 1 hour apointment for 1pm it checks if it is between tuple and if it is, it creates 2 different tuples with updated hours [(8, 13), (14, 16)], if another apointment is booked for let's say 10am, than it deletes first tuple and creates two new on it's place [(8, 10), (11, 13), (14, 16)] and so on and so on.
I have a problem with "translating" my python code to the Django model. Can't find a way to store list of tuples in accesable way to be able to edit it. I read on different post that list of tuples can be stored in many to one relation but I dont think that it will be good in my case.

Comment: Have you considered a JSON field?

Comment: not sure how excaly i could store it in json

Comment: You can store a string field and read them back as Python data using `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: But JSON is easier to query if your database supports that.

Comment: JSON can do arrays of arrays of numbers.

Comment: okay i will try it and see what I can do with it. Thanks for an idea @gilch

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONField but it is actually a textfield, I personally would convert the list into json format then store it as text in your model

Answer (score 0):

You can do a many-to-one relation between a barber table and an appointments table. The appointments would each have a barber id foreign key, a start time, and an end time column.

| appointment_id | barber_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 11 | 13 |
| 3 | 1 | 14 | 16 |

You'd probably want to keep an index on the `barber_id`.